# L0 and Inf Norms plotting with Contour, Contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf, norm

I am trying to plot different norms with contourf and contour. I have succeeded with all norms except zero-norm and inf-norm.
What is the right way to draw similar graphs for 0-norm and inf-norm?

Here is my code:

```
`p_values = [0., 0.04, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 7, np.inf]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101), np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=(len(p_values) + 1)// 2,
                     nrows=2, figsize=(14, 7))
for p, ax in zip(p_values, axes.flat):
    if p != 0:
        zz = ((np.abs((xx))**p) + (np.abs((yy))**p))**(1./p)
    else:
        zz = np.full_like(xx, np.sum(xx !=0)) 
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, zz, 30, cmap='bwr')
    ax.contour(xx,yy,zz, [1], colors='red', linewidths = 2) 
    proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, facecolor='red')]
plt.show()`
```

[My code and graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrFrT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me mention that numpy provides [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) which could simplify things, when calculating norms. In the remainder I will stick to the attempt from the question to calculate the norm manually though.

#### L∞ norm

The L∞ norm would be the suppremum of the two arrays. This can easily be calculated using `numpy.maximum`.

```
zz = np.maximum(np.abs(xx),np.abs(yy))
```

#### L0 "norm"

The L0 "norm" would be defined as the number of non-zero elements. For the 2D case it can hence take the values 0 (both zero), 1 (one zero), or 2 (both non-zero). Depicting this function as a contour plot is not really succefull because the function essentially deviates from 2 only along two lines in the plot. Using an `imshow` plot would show it though.

```
zz = (xx != 0).astype(int) + (yy != 0).astype(int)
ax.imshow(zz, cmap='bwr', aspect="auto")
```

[image]

#### Complete example.

In total the plot could then look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p_values = [0., 0.04, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 7, np.inf]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101), np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=(len(p_values) + 1)// 2,
                     nrows=2, figsize=(14, 7))
for p, ax in zip(p_values, axes.flat):
    if p == 0:
        zz = (xx != 0).astype(int) + (yy != 0).astype(int)
        ax.imshow(zz, cmap='bwr', extent=(xx.min(),xx.max(),yy.min(),yy.max()), aspect="auto")
    else:
        if np.isinf(p):
            zz = np.maximum(np.abs(xx),np.abs(yy))
        else:
            zz = ((np.abs((xx))**p) + (np.abs((yy))**p))**(1./p)
        ax.contourf(xx, yy, zz, 30, cmap='bwr')
        ax.contour(xx,yy,zz, [1], colors='red', linewidths = 2) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar answer, with the usage of [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) and beautiful latex legend:

```
p_values = [0., 0.04, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 7, np.inf]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101),
                     np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=(len(p_values) + 1)// 2,
                         nrows=2, figsize=(16, 7))

for p, ax in zip(p_values, axes.flat):
    h = np.linalg.norm([xx, yy], ord=p, axis=0)
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, h, 20, cmap='coolwarm')
    ax.contour(xx, yy, h, [1], colors='#fd02d5')
    ax.legend([mlines.Line2D([], [], color="#fd02d5")], [f"$x: \|x\|_{{{p}}}=1$",])
plt.show()
```

[image: output.png]